# HTC Evo 4G LTE not found in ADB

Tags: adb

I am having a problem with adb not finding my evo 4g lte. I have USB debugging selected. The phone is updated to 3.17, so some of the options, like charge only/disk drive have changed (now i think my only options are HTC Sync and disk drive). I am using the most updated version of the Android SDK. I'm running a fully updated windows 7 box. I have tried all of my USB ports, adb kill-server/adb start-server. I even created an .ini file with the hex version of the device USB/VID id (based on the HTC Sync setting, the phone shows only as Android Phone in my windows device manager. I have not yet tried switching it to disk drive), and nothing has worked. The phone's bootloader is unlocked via htcdev, but is otherwise stock. And, oddly enough, my old evo 4g which is rooted and running CM9 can be found, so I think it's got to be something with the new phone, I am just not sure what. I've been researching this over the last few days and have tried everything I have found, all to no avail. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Internal port is faulty. Two terminals for charging ,two for data, the data one(s) may have fractured from.the board.